# How to use two 'for' loops to create lists in sequence?

Tags: list, loops, for-loop

I want to create 21 lists.

data is an array (1632, 21)

`x0, x1, ..., x21 = []`

```py
for i in range(60, 1632):
    x0.append(data[i-60:i,0])

for i in range(60, 1632):
    x1.append(data[i-60:i,1])

for i in range(60, 1632):
    x2.append(data[i-60:i,2])
```

How to create them in two loops? Great thanks!

I tried:

```py
for j in range(21):
    for i in range(60, 1632)):
        x['j'].append(data[i-60:i,j])
```

```py
for j in range(21):
    for i in range(60, 1632)):
        x'j'.append(data[i-60:i,j])
```